# Custom sObject sorting with 'implements comparable'

Tags: apex, sort, wrapper-class

I'm trying to perform a sort on a list of custom sObjects using the 'implements comparable' wrapper method. I'm running into some error that it seems isn't affecting anyone else. My custom object looks like so:

```
gAlert:{
    title: text,
    published: date
}
```

I'm trying to sort by published.

I tried implementing the following:

```
public class gAlertWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) 
    {
        gAlertWrapper gAlertWrapper = (gAlertWrapper) compareTo;
        if (gAlert__c.published__c == gAlertWrapper.gAlert__c.published__c) return 0;
        if (gAlert__c.published__c > gAlertWrapper.gAlert__c.published__c) return 1;
        return -1;        
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Variable does not exist: gAlert__c

from the following line:

```
if (gAlert__c.published__c == gAlertWrapper.gAlert__c.published__c) return 0;
```

The problem seems to be in gAlertWrapper.gAlert__c.published_c

What am I doing incorrectly?

I tried implementing a constructor, like so:

```
public gAlert__c gA;
public gAlertWrapper(gAlert__c g) {
        gA = g;
    }
```

But that didn't seem to work either... How can I piece this together?

Thanks!

EDIT: Everything seemed to be working fine, as there were no compiling errors. But at run time there was a

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I know it's not the xml I'm parsing in - it's the same stuff from before.

Here is the code that is trying to save values to entry.gA:

```
public static list<gAlert__c> getAlerts(string url){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
                Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();

                string title = '';
                integer count = 1;

        list<gAlert__c> results = new list<gAlert__c>();
        gAlertWrapper entry = new gAlertWrapper();      
        for(Dom.XMLNode child:address.getChildElements()){
            string childElement = child.getName();
            if(childElement == 'title'){
                title = child.getText();
            }
            else if(childElement == 'entry'){
                for(Dom.XmlNode grandChild : child.getChildElements()){
                        string grandChildElement = grandChild.getName();
                    if(grandChildElement == 'title'){
                        entry.gA.title__c = grandChild.getText();
                    }
                    else if(grandChildElement == 'link'){
                        entry.gA.link__c = grandChild.getAttributeValue('href', null);
                    }
                    else if(grandChildElement == 'published'){
                        entry.gA.published__c = grandChild.getText().replace('Z','').replace('T',' ');
                    }
                    else if(grandChildElement == 'content'){
                        entry.gA.content__c = grandChild.getText();
                    }
                    else if(grandChildElement == 'author'){ //this is the last element in the tree
                        results.add(entry.gA.clone(false,false,false,false));
                        entry.gA.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
    public class gAlertWrapper implements Comparable{
        public gAlert__c gA;
        //public gAlertWrapper(gAlert__c g) {
        //gA = g;
        //}
        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            gAlertWrapper gAlertWrapper = (gAlertWrapper) compareTo;
            if (gA.published__c == gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 0;
            if (gA.published__c > gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 1;
            return -1; 
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error at the line:

```
entry.gA.title__c = grandChild.getText();
```

I know it isn't the grandVhild.getText(), since that hasn't changed. What is strange is that I would imagine the null pointer would reflect the right side of the equation no?

I guess I'm really fumbling my way around learning how to use this comparable class..

Thank you so much for your patience and help. Happy to upvote everything you've written - it all deserves it.

Comment: Can you post your wrapper class?

Comment: I had thought the Public Class gAlertWrapper is the wrapper class... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class gAlertWrapper implements Comparable{
   public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    gAlertWrapper gAlertWrapper = (gAlertWrapper) compareTo;
    if (gA.published__c == gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 0;
    if (gA.published__c > gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 1;
    return -1;        
  }
}
```

Following is the correct syntax

Corrected completed code

```
public static list<gAlert__c> getAlerts(string url){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
            Dom.XMLNode address = doc.getRootElement();

            string title = '';
            integer count = 1;

    list<gAlert__c> results = new list<gAlert__c>();
    gAlert__c gAlert=new gAlert__c();
    gAlertWrapper entry = new gAlertWrapper(gAlert);      
    for(Dom.XMLNode child:address.getChildElements()){
        string childElement = child.getName();
        if(childElement == 'title'){
            title = child.getText();
        }
        else if(childElement == 'entry'){
            for(Dom.XmlNode grandChild : child.getChildElements()){
                    string grandChildElement = grandChild.getName();
                if(grandChildElement == 'title'){
                    entry.gA.title__c = grandChild.getText();
                }
                else if(grandChildElement == 'link'){
                    entry.gA.link__c = grandChild.getAttributeValue('href', null);
                }
                else if(grandChildElement == 'published'){
                    entry.gA.published__c = grandChild.getText().replace('Z','').replace('T',' ');
                }
                else if(grandChildElement == 'content'){
                    entry.gA.content__c = grandChild.getText();
                }
                else if(grandChildElement == 'author'){ //this is the last element in the tree
                    results.add(entry.gA.clone(false,false,false,false));
                    entry.gA.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
public class gAlertWrapper implements Comparable{
    public gAlert__c gA;
    public gAlertWrapper(gAlert__c g) {
    gA = g;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        gAlertWrapper gAlertWrapper = (gAlertWrapper) compareTo;
        if (gA.published__c == gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 0;
        if (gA.published__c > gAlertWrapper.gA.published__c) return 1;
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So that seems to have worked.. But Now I'm getting another error: Constructor Not Defined [apexclass.gAlertWrapper].<Constructor>(). I'm probably not putting the constructor in the right place. I've added a section to my question with the new code

Comment: `return gA.published__c.daysBetween(gAlertWrapper.ga.published__c);` Here's a little trick-- you don't need to return 0, 1, or -1. Just a number between -MAX_INT and +MAX_INT-1, where MAX_INT is 2,147,483,648.

Comment: public gAlertWrapper(gAlert__c g) {
            gA = g;
        }  Please delete this if you dont need constructor .

Comment: Ok, deleted constructor... But now the object doesn't have all the fields that gAlert had. For instance, gAlert has a title field. When I create a new gAlertWrapper object, it doesn't seem to have these fields. I've updated the above question to reflect the problem

Comment: Its entry.gA.title__c = grandChild.getText();  please mark as answered .Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to mark this as correct (and upvote everyone of your comments) when the code works. Each step of the way is producing more errors, so the solution is only half implemented. the introduction of the gAlertWrapper and gA has broken the code. If you wouldn't mind, can you see what's going wrong?

Comment: Have corrected the code .Let me know if any issues .

Comment: Also running for loop you may like to collect in a list